# How to add <div> inside WordPress comments loop?

Tags: comments

I know we can add  in posts loop using in index.php and in single.php by filtering the content but I don't know how to add  after certain comments. For example, if a post have comments, after 30 comments, I want to display a  under which I want to put an advertisement. Then after 60 comments, I want to have second  and so on. I am not sure if this can be done via plugins but I am refraining myself to use plugins to reduce load on the site.

Please help!

Comment: I’d guess this is best done in the theme where you have the comments loop: declare a counter before the start of the loop, and at the bottom of the loop increment it then check if it’s a multiple of 30 and add your div advert if it is.

Comment: @Rup can you please share me an example for this.